# How to exclude from counting only the dates I wrote in the array not all the range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to subtract the special_days from the range of requested_days .

The special_days are set in an array ,and i want to exclude from counting only the dates i putted there not the hole as a range,like it is working know.

```
def skip_holidays
  special_days = ["2017-05-10", "2017-05-12"].map(&:to_date)
  accepted_days = []
  refused_days = []
  (start_data..end_data).each do |requested_date|
    accepted_days << requested_date unless special_days.include?(requested_date)
    refused_days << requested_date if special_days.include?(requested_date)
  end
  accepted_day_count = accepted_days.count
  refused_days_count = refused_days.count

  rez= accepted_day_count- refused_days_count
  return rez
end
```

Comment: Remove the `return` from `return sd`, leaving only `sd`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It `return`s so it's only one instance

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the whole method where i am trying to count the holiday days in our country and dont count them.def largo_festat
   count1=0
   special_days=["2017-05-12","2017-05-18"]
   
   special_days.each do |sd|
  

    
 
  
   if ((start_data..end_data) === sd)
   count1 = count1 + 1
   numeroji=sd.count
   return numeroji
   
      numero=(end_data - start_data).to_i 
      numro1=numero - count1
      return numro1
      count1 = count1 + 1
  else
      numero=(end_data - start_data).to_i 
      return numero

  end
    end
  
end

Comment: def largo_festat
   count1=0
   special_days=["2017-05-12","2017-05-18"]
   
   special_days.each do |sd|
  

    
 
  
   if ((start_data..end_data) === sd)
   count1 = count1 + 1
   numeroji=sd.count
   return numeroji
   
      numero=(end_data - start_data).to_i 
      numro1=numero - count1
      return numro1
      count1 = count1 + 1
  else
      numero=(end_data - start_data).to_i 
      return numero

  end
    end
  
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me break this down to a more general approach, since you did not really provide any code for us to use.

Say you have an array of dates called `special_days` that includes dates which should be blocked.

```
special_days = ["2017-05-12","2017-05-18"]
```

Let's further say you have an array of dates an user wants to take vacations on.

```
vacation_days = ["2017-05-12","2017-05-18", "2017-05-19"]
```

In the end you want to return an array of dates which are in `vacation_days` but not in `special_days`.
To achieve this, you can simply subtract the arrays like so:

```
vacation_days - special_days
# => ["2017-05-19"]
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: Philipp thanks a lot but the c\vacation_days comes from a form where a user from calendar choose which dates he or she wants.I have a start_date and end_date.I dont know if i can put them in an array like you told me?

Comment: It's your data, you can bring it in any shape or form you want ;) without more/proper code examples we can't help you though. Just add an example of how the data you receive looks like and give code that you already wrote so we can find out the best way to get you to your desired solution ;) Add it to your question, not in a comment please.

Comment: <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :start_data %><br>
          <%= f.date_select :start_data, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year + 1 %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :end_data %><br>
              <%= f.date_select :end_data, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year + 1 %>
            </div>
        </div>    This is the form of vacation_controller from where a userr selects star_data and end_data

Comment: def largo_festat
   count1=0
   special_days=["2017-05-12","2017-05-18"]
   
   special_days.each do |sd|
    arr1=(start_data..end_data)
    arr2=arr1[]
    rez=arr2-special_days
    return  rez
  
  
  
    end
  
end   this is what i have done till now.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code formatted there.

Comment: Sorry i was looking h\for how to edit my question but i didnt find nothing.I am new to stackoverflow.  Also i dont know how to format my code here.All i want to know is how to put the range of dates start_date .. end_ in an array.These dates users select from a drop down list in a form.

Comment: There's an "edit" button below your question. Also, check out your second question you posted here. Maybe I could provide the correct answer there.